# hosting 2 websites from one machine

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, hosting, ddns

I am hosting a forum on raspberry pi using apache2 and simplemachines and i also want to make a personal website(the forum is a returned favor for a friend). Because I have dynamic ip at home i am using a ddns provider called raspctl. I know that i can use websitename.raspctl.com:81 to access my page but is there a way to forward  websitename . raspctl . com:81 to mysite.com?

Thanks and sorry for the spaces.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you familiarize yourself with the concept of virtual hosts. Since you are already using apache, this link may help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it would be beneficial if you familiarize yourself with the
>   concept of virtual hosts. Since you are already using apache, this
>   link may help: digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/… – 
>   AtomHeartFather 21 hours ago

please post it as an answer.